# Printing byte by byte

Tags: c

I am trying to make a C program which opens a file and prints its byte by byte using the Hexabyte format (%02x) for each byte.

The result should be something like this:

```
$ ./hexabyte file
43
3d
67
...
```

I know I want to use fread to do this, but I am not sure why this solution doesn't work:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<string.h>


int args_test(int args, char path[]){

  if(args < 1){
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s path\n", path);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
  if(args < 2){
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s path\n", path);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }

  if(args > 2){
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s path\n", path);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }

  return 0;
}


int open_file(char path[]){
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen(path, "r");
  char buffer[1000];

  if(!fp){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
  int len = ftell(fp);

  //Why does it not reach this loop?
  while (fread(buffer, strlen(path), 1, fp) == 1){
    printf("%02x hexabytes\n", len);
  }

  fclose(fp);

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main(int args, char* argv[]){
  if(args < 2 || args > 2){
    args_test(args, argv[0]);
  }
  args_test(args, argv[1]);
  open_file(argv[1]);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

It seems like it never reaches my while loop, and therefor never prints anything

Comment: `if(args < 2 || args > 2)` == `if (args != 2)` ;)

Comment: Haha thank you. Of course :)

Comment: It is not recommended to exit from a function, use a return instead

Comment: If you use your function in e.g. a library and it suddenly stops working, because an error occured and you do `exit(1)`, it is not the expected behavoir. It is okay of course for such small examples, but this is a no-go in a large(r) codebase.

Comment: The debugger is your friend. And for the documentation: any C textbook. You can't learn programming by copy/paste snippets. A program is not a Quilt.

Comment: @hellow: `exit` is fine if you **want** to exit. That's not about recommendations, but about different functionalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seek to the end of the file, so `fread` will have nothing to read. You need to seek back to the start.

The `fread` is also being asked to read the length of the path, which seems wrong, the way your loop is set up seems to be for 1 byte at a time.

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); // Seeks to end of file
int len = ftell(fp);

// Nothing to read, at end
while (fread(buffer, strlen(path), 1, fp) == 1){
    printf("%02x hexabytes\n", len);
}
```

Simply seek again after the `ftell`.

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); // Seeks to end of file
int len = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); // Go to start again
// Read from start, 1 byte at a time
char byte;
while (fread(&byte, 1, 1, fp) == 1){
    printf("%02X\n", (int)byte);
}
```

You could also read 1000 bytes at a time (as your `buffer` is) but then you need a second loop, or you could read the entire file, but you need to dynamically allocate the buffer (`buffer = malloc(len);`).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I see now that my file was already at the end. 

I wonder how your char byte works. The example I looked up specified the size as I did with my initial buffer, but you do something different I see. Not really sure how your fread works compared to mine, but it does seem like your implementation works as I intended mine should!

Comment: The loop reads one byte at a time, reading larger amounts at once is often used for performance, but then for this you still need 1 printf per byte or to format a string by other means.

Comment: Just have to look up some basic syntax to make sure I understand everything. But thank you for letting me know where I messed up! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the file pointer to the beginning of the file:

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Comment: That did the trick. Now it doesn't print any value though, so I will have to figure this out as well. Thought it should work when it entered the loop though. Hmm.

Comment: @kthonenice because you print `printf("%02x hexabytes\n", len);` and not the actual buffer you read

Comment: Yes, but if I try to add buffer instead of len I need to change the format from %02x?

Comment: Please get a textbook. This site is for **specific** questions about **specific** problems, not for tutoring. You will not learn C from asking singular questions, you need the foundations.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you fix the `fseek` problem, you have other issues:

```
while (fread(buffer, strlen(path), 1, fp) == 1){
  printf("%02x hexabytes\n", len);
}
```

Note that you are not reading a single byte at a time; you're reading bytes in `strlen(path)`-sized chunks at a time.

You're also not printing the byte(s) you just read; you're printing the *length of the file*.  So assuming your file size is, say, 65536 bytes, you'll get the output

```
10000 hexabytes
10000 hexabytes
10000 hexabytes
...
```

`65536 / strlen(path)` times.  I don't think that's what you want.

I think what you're going for is something more along these lines:

```
unsigned char buffer[1000]; // for arbitrary bytes, unsigned char works better.

int bytes_read = 0;

while ( (bytes_read = fread( buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, fp )) != EOF )
{
  for( int b = 0; b < bytes_read; b++ )
  {
    printf( "%02hhx\n", buffer[b] ); // %x expects unsigned *int*, use the
  }                                  // hh modifier to specify unsigned char
}
```

The expression

```
bytes_read = fread( buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, fp )
```

reads up to `sizeof buffer` (1000 in this case) bytes from `fp` and stores the number actually read to `bytes_read`.  If we haven't hit `EOF`, then we print the contents of `buffer`.